# How can I Export local datastore data to Production Google App Engine Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I wanted to export my local datastore data to my google appengine application datastore. Is there any direct and short way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read about it [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html)