# How to export Local datastore to Google App Engine Datastore with Android Studio?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a local app development server on my machine. Here I also have a local datastore named localdb.bin.

I am trying to export all the indexes or all the records to the Google App Engine Datastore. So I am trying to upload my local datastore to GAE datastore. Is there any way?

I am using Android Studio 1.0 and Java on the App Engine. And Usually I deploy the app by Build>Deploy Module to App Engine.

I have seen some answers from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903893/how-can-i-export-local-datastore-data-to-production-google-app-engine-datastore) 
and [Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp).

But they do not provide a way to do it via Android Studio. Any materials I should Check?